# Data Table Bootstrap Styling Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I've started creating simple data table with bootstrap styling based on : 
http://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html .

The result is not the same as the example, you can see here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable({});
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yb3kk8cn/

Elements above and below the table (filter and the paginanation) position is overlapping, not inline.

Comment: its fine and same as the example

Comment: In the fiddle, if you just make the result frame wider, bootstrap will put nav items inline. Something about elements colapsing and stacking when the container is [less than 970 px wide](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: Thank you, solved. It's about the size of container. What I need to do is create a wrapper with min-width.

Answer (score 2):

> Elements above and below the table (filter and the paginanation) position is overlapping, not inline.

This only happens on small screen sizes, which is more likely on jsfiddle because of the layout.

I think your fiddle looks correct otherwise. Your table headings are bold but that's an easy css fix.